# How does a site like Stackoverflow keep track of the views a post has?

Tags: database-design

I was wondering how a site like SO keeps track of the views a specific question has. They must be storing them in a separate table, right? Maybe with a FK on userID, and questionID? what about unauthenticated users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that [this post on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter) is what you are looking for. Questions involves a lot of research on SOs system while the answer sheds some light on how that system could work. It's not that trivial as one might expect.

Answer (score 0):

They probably have a table with `QuestionId`, `IPAddress`, and `Time`.

Comment: wouldn't that be a false count with multiple users behind the same IP?

Comment: Yes, it would.  There is no good way to get an accurate and spoof-resistant view count.  I don't know whether they distingiush different logged-in users on the same IP.

Comment: thats right but they may be storing some cookie data too (browser oriented) that goes into the database to give more accuracy to reports I guess